# Does 'downvote spamming' lead to a question-ban?

Tags: support, bug

Today I discovered that my Stack Overflow account has been placed under a question ban, although I **could ask questions a few days ago** (I was going to ask a question on the weekend, but I found the answer to my question before I submitted).

I've been doing some investigation, and the only question that could potentially cause the question ban to happen was [one I asked almost a month ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25714548/obtain-substring), so it doesn't exactly make sense for this question to be the cause.

I admit that I've recently been downvoting and commenting on bad questions, which *could* potentially be considered 'spam':
[image]

The 'actions' tab doesn't show the downvotes on actual questions, of which I've been downvoting more than answers.

Does this sort of downvoting cause question-bans to happen?
If not, why did I get a question ban only a couple of days ago if it is related to my question with -1 reputation almost a month ago?

I also never saw a message similar to 'You're close to a question ban', which makes the whole thing even more confusing.

Could this potentially be a bug in the Stack Exchange system?

Comment: You're not the first one to complain about this.  Not sure what's going on, they are trying to phase-in the "timed ban" feature.  New features do come with a trail of troublesome turmoil lately.  Your problem will possibly be fixed in 6 to 8 minutes/days/weeks.  Possibly accelerated by picking a better user name :)

Comment: @HansPassant This specific case isn't related to the new system. Just the good ol' block that we've had for years.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Isn't spam considered "Unsolicited Commercial Advertising?"  How does clicking a down-arrow help someone promote their fake Gucci handbags?

By "spam," I assume you mean "indiscriminate downvoting," so any answer we give you would have to address what you consider "indiscriminate."

It probably didn't help that *you asked the same question twice on September 8, and attracted 3 downvotes each time you asked.*

Comment: I thought that the Stack Exchange sites were separate with reference to the voting system and question/answer bans? This still doesn't answer the fact that I only received the question ban a couple of days ago, and as aforementioned I was able to post a question over the weekend (I was able to access the 'Ask a Question' page).

Comment: Most likely you got a downvote somewhere that pushed you over the edge.  The voting system plays a big part in such bans... how else would the software  adequately measure the community's reaction to a question or answer?

Comment: But then wouldn't I be able to see that downvote in my reputation changes (which I don't)? On Saturday when I was going to post a new question, there wasn't any notice warning me that I was close to a question ban, which should have been present if a downvote pushed me over the edge.

Comment: Ah, I see.  Well, SE has been tweaking the quality systems lately.  I did notice for a short period of time that it seemed like nobody was getting banned.

Comment: I see, perhaps the system developers have tweaked the sensitivity a little bit too much. Hopefully my answer here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26148929/app-crashes-after-updating-to-ios-sdk-8-0/26150598#26150598) will be marked as accepted and hopefully that'll get me out of the question ban.

Comment: Update: my answer for that question was just upvoted, and even the +10 rep wasn't enough to boost me back across the line.

Comment: @zyboxinternational There is a number of things that goes into the question block check - votes, deletions, closures, etc. I'm not going to discuss the specifics publicly, but let's just say you must have been right on the edge of the block because right now you aren't blocked anymore. The flip side is that you're likely still on the edge *now*, so I suggest putting extra thought and care into your next question(s).

Comment: @AnnaLear Nope, I'm still question-banned.

Comment: @zyboxinternational You weren't when I looked yesterday. As I said, you're right on the edge.

Comment: @AnnaLear Odd..

Comment: @AnnaLear The question-ban still exists although I have 20+ more reputation than before. I don't think this question-ban is reputation-based, and I need to ask a question that's pretty urgent. Please could the ban be lifted?

Comment: @cybermonkey There's nobody who can lift one of these bans. It's fully automatic. Having said that... you're not banned *right now*.